# Generate html or docx answer key for schoice or mchoice questions

Tags: r-exams

For proofreading purposes, to circulate a draft to a teaching assistant, I would like to generate an answer key. I generate draft exams using either `exams2html()` or `exams2pandoc()`, but these don't have a key. I looked at the arguments for these two functions, but didn't see anything clearly related to showing answers on outputs. The closest I could find was the `solution` argument that seems to alter the presentation of the question rather than displaying the answer.

`exams2pandoc(e, solution = "Answer")`: This changes the output question format to list "Answer" rather than the default "Solution".

`exams2html(e, solution = "Answer")`: This does not show an "Answer" but the default does not seem to show "Solution" so I suppose that's no surprise.

I searched in the R/exams documentation, R-Forge, and here on StackOverflow. However, I was unable to locate instructions or guidance on this. Any help generating a key for a draft exam would be much appreciated. Sorry in advance if I missed something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the main purpose of R/exams is to generate large numbers of randomized questions, a classical answer key is typically of limited use (because you wouldn't want to go through dozens or hundreds of random variations of answer keys). That's why there is not so much emphasis on answer keys in R/exams.

However, there are tools you can use. On the command line there is `exams_metainfo()`, e.g.:

```
exm <- c("capitals.Rmd", "swisscapital.Rmd", "switzerland.Rmd")
set.seed(0)
res <- exams2html(exm)
exams_metainfo(res)
## exam1
##     1. Capitals: 1, 5
##     2. Swiss Capital: 1
##     3. About Switzerland: 1, 2
```

The `print()` method for the meta-information can also be tweaked a little bit, see http://www.R-exams.org/general/tamiu_finance/ for some practical examples.

If you want to display the answer key with check boxes, then the package ships with a suitable template for `exams2pdf()`:

```
set.seed(0)
exams2pdf(exm, template = "solution.tex")
```

This includes the following on the title page:

[image: exams2pdf solution]

Of course, you can also tweak the `"solution.tex"` template further to adapt it to your specific needs. To get started with this look at `demo-pdf.R` produced by

```
exams_skeleton(writer = "exams2pdf")
```

Finally, a quick clarification regarding the `solution` argument in `exams2pandoc()` and `exams2html()`, taken from the corresponding help pages.

> `question`: character or logical. Should the question be included in the
> output? If 'question' is a character it will be used as a
> header for resulting questions.
>
> `solution`: character or logical, see argument 'question'.

Comment: `exams_metainfo(e)` returned the error `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : subscript out of bounds`

Comment: `exams2pdf(e, template = "solution.tex")` returned the error ```Error in texi2dvi(out_tex[j], pdf = TRUE, clean = TRUE, quiet = quiet) : 
  unable to run pdflatex on 'solution1.tex'
LaTeX errors:
! LaTeX Error: File `a4wide.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.5 ^^M
       
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!```

Comment: This didn't solve the issue, but I probably need to fix some other things. I'm using R/exams for the sole purpose of putting large numbers of questions into Canvas.

Comment: For `exams_metainfo()`: You need to use the output of an `exams2xyz()` function, not the input. For `exams2pdf()`: Install the a4wide.sty LaTeX package.

Comment: The key piece of information I failed to understand was: `<- exams2html(exm)` followed by `exams_metainfo(res)`. This gave the desired result, which I copied from the console to a text file--perfect. I also got a key by `exams_metainfo(exams2html(e))`.